# CSS Irregular rows, row of 8, row of 8, repeated

Tags: css

I'd like to make a set of irregular rows of boxes using VW and VH units.

I'd like a row of 8 boxes followed by a row of 7 boxes, followed by a row of 7 boxes, etc, for any number of boxes. I feel this should be possible with nth-child however I can't see to manage it.

Here's what I've got so far

https://jsfiddle.net/kjLt55ne/

```
.box:nth-child(9), .box:nth-child(24n+24) {margin-left: 5.7vw; background-color: red;}
.box:nth-child(16n) {background-color:green; clear: left;}
```

In theory I should be able to do:

- Set clear: right on every 16th element
- set margin-left on every 16th element starting from 9

However, this doesn't quite work. Can anyone help me solve this for any number of elements?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out almost immediately after posting the question!

```
.hex:nth-child(16) {clear: left; background-color: red;}
.hex:nth-child(15n+16) {clear: left; background-color: red;}
.hex:nth-child(9) {margin-left: 5.7vw;}
.hex:nth-child(15n+9) {margin-left: 5.7vw;}
```